# What is the function of this limb system?

Tags: creature-design, fantasy-races, anatomy, merfolk, sea-creatures

The Globadob is a strange fish with a strange anatomy. Most notably is its lower half, which features a structure that is not seen in any other animal

This structure is composed of a ring of legs, which are broad and flipper-like, within another ring of similar but shorter limbs, which are attached higher up on the body and are too short to reach the ground. Both limb types are inflexible and resemble lobed fins, and so couldn't be used for manipulation

**If it were a real animal as described, what is the most plausible function of this strange array of limbs?**

Comment: VTC:Not About Worldbuilding. (a) The purpose of the [anatomically correct series](https://worldbuilding.meta.stackexchange.com/q/2797/40609) (ACS) is to realistically design the physiology of a well-specified mythical or fictional creature. Please ***do not*** use the phrase "anatomically correct" in any way not related to the series. (b) You're asking about the medieval misinterpretation of an actual fish. The ACS doesn't explain why, it rationalizes. In other words *you're supposed to explain why* as a requirement of the ACS. (\*continued\*)

Comment: (c) This Stack focuses on helping, in this case, you to develop and consistently use the rules and systems of your fictional world. The medieval misinterpretation of a fish is not your fictional world, so this falls under the rule that we don't answer questions about 3rd party or commercial worlds. VTC:Not about Worldbuilding. On a personal note: we're really not your personal sounding board and you've bounced, IMO, too many random questions off of us that obviously don't relate to any fictional world you're trying to build.

Comment: @JoinJBHonCodidact Have my edits made this question allowable?

Comment: No, Ichthys. The Sea Monk isn't a fictional creature of *your creation.* Why doesn't basic research into existing creatures solve your need to ask this off-topic question? Don't like octopus? How about jelly-fish (propulsion)? You're expected to do research to solve actual problems that *you have* before asking here. You're not supposed to flood the Stack with train-of-consciousness questions that feel like you're bored but too lazy to use Google. (I am a little irritated, and I apologize... but I don't believe in dishonesty, so you're getting my unfiltered response.)

Comment: @JoinJBHonCodidact 1. If you think fictional worlds only ever contain elements purely from the author's mind, then I'd advise you to look at some more media. Or perhaps just look through your own questions/answers. 2. Neither the octopus, the jellyfish, nor any other animal that I know to exist has anything like double limb-ring described here. And even if there were, would it be anywhere near enough to the sea-monk for a useful comparison?

Comment: (a) The reason I don't care about other media is that [this Stack has rules](https://worldbuilding.meta.stackexchange.com/q/7334/40609). If I've asked about 3rd party/commercial worlds in my own questions, please identify any from after the establishing meta discussion I just linked. (b) The fact that no terrestrial creature is exactly like the Sea Monk is irrelevant. You asked for a function. You rejected one, I gave you a second, both trivially obtainable through research.

Comment: @JoinJBHonCodidact (a) That rule is predicated on copyright, which the sea-monk predates by 2 centuries and wouldn't apply to a widespread zoological misconception like the sea-monk. (b) It does matter that the limb structure is different, for the same reason that you couldn't generalize human locomotion to an air-breathing squid

Comment: No, it ***does not.*** This Stack focuses on worlds of *your own creation.* The only exception I'm aware of is the Anatomically Correct Series (human mythology, which this also is not), which only focuses on *physiology.* The answer to this question would be a prerequisite for ACS. If you want the last word, it's all yours, but my VTC stands. Please do not ask random questions here. They'd be better suited for Quora or Reddit.

Comment: @JoinJBHonCodidact I've edited the question again. Is it still somehow about a third-party work?

Comment: I gotta agree with JBH here. I'm all in for helping with creature concepts, but you've been recently bouncing some unfortunate questions which seem a bit more motivated by sheer curiosity than by actual problems with figuring things through research on your own, particularly the event regarding the 3 simultaneous question about hybrids between centaurs and "similar" creatures, one of which asked about what the hybrid of a donkey centaur and a zebra centaur would look like, which I found out about 10 seconds later by typing "donkey zebra hybrid" on google.

Comment: Also mind clarifying a bit the ring of legs part? Is it meant to be like what's seen in the arrangement of cephalopod arms, but with fins? Or maybe something similar?

Comment: I'm afraid it is quite off-topic. For the question to work, you would need to tell us what the function is, and ask us about the parameters and requirements of the form. This is arse about face, another riddle, where you've provided us with the answer and are expecting us to come-up with the question.

Comment: @ARogueAnt. It's a simple question about why a species would have a particular trait. Just because it could be figured out the other way doesn't mean that it needs to be done that way

Comment: @IchthysKing While the edits have technically overcome my previous complaints, per the [help/on-topic], questions "must be specific and answerable." Also per the [help/dont-ask], "To prevent your question from being flagged and possibly removed, avoid asking subjective questions where every answer is equally valid." You're asking an opinion-based question because you're not actually trying to solve a problem. You still don't have a question that meets all the rules.

Comment: We do "how" not "why".  "Why" always invokes opinion-based answers and so it's mostly (unless very carefully arranged) off-topic. The occasional "why" gets through, but how many of your questions have fit that pattern?

Comment: @ARogueAnt. That's one of the most succinct explanations I've ever seen. Mind if I add it to my list of comment responses?

Comment: @JoinJBHonCodidact How can every possible function for a structure be equally plausible? Is it equally plausible that the outer ring is for stabilisation as it is that it's specifically for tricking pangolins into suicide?

Comment: Copyright 2021, pay per use ;) @JoinJBHonCodidact

Comment: Ichthys, do you really not understand how this Stack works after asking so many questions? The phrase "equally plausible" refers to the answers from the perspective of selecting a best answer. You are *required* to ask a question that has the actual intent of a single best answer. From the [help/on-topic], questions "must include context and must include restrictions/requirements." The purpose of that is to ensure the plausibility that only one answer is best and it's not just *your* favorite answer. And your example, indeed, proves the point.

Comment: This chain of comments is far too long, but here's the simple reality: You've asked a question of the basic form, "I've come up with this really cool aesthetic, but I can't for the life of me guess what its purpose would be, does anyone have any ideas?" That question form is ***off-topic.*** It's world*guessing,* not worldbuilding. It's like God creating the platypus and turning to an angel and asking, "you know, that beak looks really cool, but I don't really know what it's for, got any ideas?" In short, it's inviting a discussion, and that's ***off-topic.***

Comment: @JoinJBHonCodidact "If it were a real animal as described, what is the most plausible function of this strange array of limbs?" What are these, if not restrictions and requirements?

Comment: @JoinJBHonCodidact What discussion is there to be over the most plausible function for a form that wouldn't equally happen about the most plausible form for a function?

Comment: @IchthysKing Were it a real animal, real scientists would observe its real behavior and *determine* what the limbs' purpose would be. You have provided NO restrictions or requirements. Asking, "these limbs are for propulsion, I've looked at jellyfish, but I can't determine how much strength per-gram must exist for the limbs. I expect the creature to weigh 35 kg. How much strength should they have?" would be an on-topic question.